# Drupal field of type "Node Reference" filtered by custom field

Tags: drupal, content-type, custom-fields

I have created a content type named **Contact**.

I want to make one of the fields, **Relation**, in this type reference a node of the same type.

So I have created a field of type **Node Reference**. This gives me a field which is auto-completed by the title of the type. What I would like is to auto-complete by the first name and/or last name.

I created a view for the contacts, in which I added the filters for Last Name and First Name, and in the preview it does what I want.

However, how do I use it in my field to achieve what I want?

Thanks in advance,

Yusuf

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the node title for something specific? If not, you could try a module like http://drupal.org/project/auto_nodetitle which can hide the title and automatically fill it based on a pattern.

Comment: oh, that's a nice one; I'll be using it later on; but my problem is not exactly this for the time being..  What I need right now is searching for a node, through the text field, by entering the first part of either first or last name..